# QNAP is showing the Quick Configuration screen

Tags: qnap

I have a QNAP which was working find and all disks were healthy yesterday.  I powered down the QNAP using the proper methods of logging in and choosing the shut down option.

However, now I am trying to switch it back on, but it is showing me the Quick Configuration screen:

[image]

If I go through this configuration wizard, will all my files end up getting deleted?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @ScottieH, I did solve this in the end.  I had to re-seat all the drives and after that it worked fine.